# Where do I change the .NET framework in Visual Studio Community?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

How do I change the .NET framework target in Visual Studio Community Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the target Framework version in Visual Studio by right clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer and clicking "Properties". The following dialog will open - you can change the Framework in the "Application" section:

[image]

---

Alternatively, in Visual Studio 2017 and newer, when the project uses the new SDK csproj format (.NET Standard and .NET Core templates) you can right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click "Edit Project File" to make the change manually. I find this quicker.

Example of a single framework target:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Multi-targetting example:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45;net46</TargetFrameworks>
```